In attempt at: wsl --import I get "The system cannot find the path specified."
To use with OpenFOAM, I am following a YouTube video on Hassan Berro's channel titled "Installing official Salome Meca on Windows 10/11 using WSL2" in an attempt to install on Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045 with updates current.
Local Disk C: has 10 GB free.
Am using Windows Power Shell.
wsl is verified as version 2, set as default. Here's the offending line:
wsl --import smeca C:\SalomeMeca .\D:\SALOME\smeca_2022_wsl2_ubuntu_22.04.tar
For days I've tried to get the import of smeca_2022_wsl2_ubuntu_22.04.tar to work, have tried sfc /scannow but that didn't help.
I've seen no posts on Microsoft.com or Git mentioning Salome Meca so can only assume it's something stupid I'm doing or my system.
I am desperate to get this working soon.
Any help is appreciated.
I tried my best to duplicate exactly the steps in the video with the exception of installing on Windows 10 instead of Windows 11
I initially placed the tar on Desktop as was done in the tutorial, created destination folder on C:
no joy, copied path of destination: C:\SalomeMeca from explorer in hopes at solution. Moved the tar to \D:\SALOME\smeca_2022_wsl2_ubuntu_22.04.tar to free up space on C:.
I was expecting it to extract the virtual machine to C:\SalomeMeca

D:\some\dirs\to\filename is a valid Windows pathname. \D:\samething is NOT and .\D:\samething also is NOT. Use the valid (and correct) pathname and not an invalid one.
